# How to run scala worksheet with options ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm running some code in a Scala worksheet using IntelliJ and get the following compilation warning at the message window:

> Warning: there was one deprecation warning (since 2.11.0); re-run with -deprecation for details

This is kind of weird that IntelliJ doesn't show me the deprecation warning at the editor window but never mind.
How can I set my worksheet to run with this flag ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open request to add this feature:

- [SCL-10469](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10469) Worksheet does not respect console scalacOptions

Comment: so basically my only option to see the deprecation inside Intellij is copy and paste the code from the worksheet to main and run it with the flag?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be fixed.

1. Click "Show worksheet settings" gear icon
2. Click "Show compiler profiles settings" gear icon
3. Add the option in "Additional compiler options" field